# NullPointerException when getting text from a specific element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, classname

I'm learning how to use selenium by using java. I got a problem. Having html code:

```
<h2 class="cart-popup-product__title">Laptop Dell XPS 13 2015 13.3inch Touch (Xám) - Hàng nhập khẩu</h2>
```

And this is my code to get text:

```
By productName = By.className("cart-popup-product__title");
public String ProductName(){
    String pn = driver.findElement(productName).getText();
    return pn;
}
```

Eclipse display error message: `NullPointerException`. I have tried to use `xpath`, `cssSelector` but it's not working.

*Update: I've solved my problem. I just add `this.driver = driver;` to constructor. I forgot to add when initialize constructor.

Thanks all for helping me improve.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You should try to find out which variable is null. driver?

Comment: He should read and attach a stacktrace so we weren't to guess.

Comment: I got this problem 2 days ago. I have tried to use many solutions: search, debug. Base on my knowledge until now, i can't solve this problem. So i decide to ask on there. Thanks all for helping me.

Comment: At least show your stacktrace. We cannot surely find out which is producing the `NPE`.

Comment: I wouldn't award an Oscar :(

Comment: Instead of recording the problem describe it add post the stack trace.

Comment: I'm searching how to get stacktrace, i'm newbie :D.

Comment: I've used this:
String s = getStackTraceString(e);
System.out.println("Stack Trace String " + s); and I got this: http://pastebin.com/dpdTL75f is it stack trace?

Comment: Can you show us more code?

Comment: Haha, thanks all. I've solved my problem. 
Just add `this.driver = driver;` to constructor.

Answer (score -1):

It can possible be an another element with the same class name without any text.

FindElement() method does not throw a NoSuchElementException - this is a clear sign that the element was found.

Is it possible to find element in browser console by the following locator?
Also you can try to find desired element's parent and then call getText() method.

Comment: `WebElement` without text will give an empty `String`, not `null`. And even if it was null the OP doesn't do anything with it so it wont cause `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've solved my prolem. Just add `this.driver = driver;` to constructor.